# Apple In-App Purchases - what happens with active subscriptions after remove item from sale

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, recurring-billing, in-app

I would like to increase the price of the auto-renewal In-App Purchase subscription. I want to keep the current subscriptions active for the old price and the new subscriptions for the new price only. When I create a second In-App product, users can switch to a cheaper plan in phone settings.

What happens if I untick the "Clear for Sale" checkbox in App Store Connect? It will cancel all active subscriptions till I delete the product or not? If not, how can I increase the price for the new subscribers only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are new options from Apple which allows a developer to increase the price for new subscribers and keep the old price for existing.

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc9870599e